# Is buying BTC on localbitcoins.com safe?

Tags: exchanges

Hi I'm looking into getting some bitcoins, and was wondering if buying locally from someone on localbitcoins.com would be safe.

Has anyone had any experience with that?

Answer (score 1):

It's a reputable website, but it's really up to the person you are buying from.

Do your research, choose a person with good reputation, make sure you understand how the escrow system works, and under no circumstances release escrow early.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the people you meet with. Dangers range from getting mugged to ending up with fake bills, as in this story:

http://letstalkbitcoin.com/e50-moneys-we-believe-in/#.UngBC8PXt2U

Haven't tried it myself yet, but from what I hear it's generally a good way to trade bitcoins. Just be extra careful.